Page items values do not refresh in static content region
I have static content region with HTML
<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&APP_SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=GET_FILE:::FILE_ID:&P12_FILE_ID.">Download &P12_FILE_NAME.</a>

Page items P12_FILE_ID, P12_FILE_NAME values filled by dynamic action. At page load they are NULL. Problem is APP_ID and APP_SESSION get substituted correctly but P12_FILE_ID, P12_FILE_NAME are still NULL in static content region.
Update:
Here are the source of my attempt at dynamic content region.
declare
  l_html_link clob;
begin
  l_html_link := '<div id="DOWNLOAD_LINK"><a href="f?p=' || :APP_ID || ':1:' || :APP_SESSION
  || ':APPLICATION_PROCESS=GET_FILE:::FILE_ID:' || :P12_FILE_ID || '">Download '
  || :P12_FILE_NAME || '</a></div>';

  return l_html_link;
end;

Also I had to add Static ID = DOWNLOAD_LINK to my region properties. Because of "Dynamic Content region must use a template with ID attribute" error.

Static regions are created at page rendering. That means that the value in that href exists in the page as it was rendered with the page item value at rendering time - it does not reflect session changes in any of the referenced page items. Here is one possible solution:
If you're on a more recent version of APEX then you should use the region type "Dynamic content" and refresh that region as part of the dynamic action actions. Make sure to list the page items that are affected by the dynamic action in the "Page Items to Submit" attribute of the Dynamic Content region.
-- UPDATE --
Here is an example based on your update. There is a static content region with an url that has 2 page items.
page items:
Page items P285_FILE_NAME and P285_FILE_ID, both text fields
static content region:
PL/SQL Function Body returning a CLOB:
declare
  l_href VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_html_link clob;
begin

  l_href := apex_string.format('f?p=%0:1:%1:APPLICATION_PROCESS=GET_FILE:::FILE_ID:%2',:APP_ID,:APP_SESSION,:P285_FILE_ID);

  l_html_link := apex_string.format('<div id="DOWNLOAD_LINK"><a href="%0">Download %1 (%2)</a></div>',l_href,:P285_FILE_NAME,l_href);

  return l_html_link;
end;

Page Items to Submit: P285_FILE_NAME,P285_FILE_ID

dynamic action:
Dynamic action on change of items P285_FILE_NAME,P285_FILE_ID with a single  action of refresh dynamic content region;
result:

Note, it's easier to build the url using apex_page.get_url. That will include checksums if applicable. docs

I changed to Dynamic Content Region. Rewrote the code. In dynamic action after setting these items I refresh Dynamic Content Region. I see values of P12_FILE_ID, P12_FILE_NAME on the page. But link generates without them.

Can you update the question with the source of your dynamic region ? The page items in the dynamic region have to be treated as pl/sql variables, not as plain text

Added an example

@Vitaly did you get it to work with this extra info I provided ?

No, I couldn't get it to work. All 4 items was in the "Page Items to Submit" field. I made workaround without generating link.

Strange, this is very basic APEX functionality. If you'd like to get to the bottom of it let me know, hth.
